# Can i send buffer in c# client to java SocketChannel server?

Tags: java, c#, sockets, networking, socketchannel

I am creating my game server with java nio, But i can not find how to use socketchannel or send data in c#, how can I solve this problem.  Just use i/o?

Comment: Assuming you would like to do this synchronously there is an example on how to use Sockets for synchronous communication on MSDN : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb5kfec7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I herd that nio does not use stream type but it does not makes any matter?

Comment: As long as you send your payload in a format both languages can understand, it is irrelevant if java uses NIO and C# something different. Point is: You send bytes over well probably TCP - right? So you can use your preferred method for sending / receiving bytes. You only need to have a decent protocol. Be it some byte-protocol you invented yourself or some standards like JSON, Xml, ... to be able to serialize / deserialize your payload.

Comment: Speaking of a **game** server, you should consider the needed throughput and reliability, though. For example if you have like a first-person-shooter, you will probably like to use UDP with a very simple protocol, because it does not matter that each single packet arrives, but they should be exchanged on a very high frequency.

Comment: @Fildor thanks a lot !! I think know i understand what is the point. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

Object communication through sockets has many limitations. You have to define some kind of communication protocol to understand data on both sides. You can also send serialized data ensuring that deserialization is done in the same way on the other side. You should use some other mechanism such as WebServices (SOAP or RESTful) for ease of use.

Comment: I like to use the websocket + json combination when sending data between on network between application using different languages. Both of these are pretty well supported on many of the mainstream languages

Comment: @Sidewinder94 OP is speaking of a **game** server. So choice of technologies will highly depend on the type of data to be exchanged.

Comment: @Fildor I completely agree, It was just meant as a starting point, not as a full blown miracle solution ^^, I may not have expressed it correctly though.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!! But is there any benefit by splitting the server like that??